# Tweepy: Find all tweets in a specific language

Tags: twitter, tweepy

I'd like to extract all tweets in the Arabic language in all countries.

I modified the code in this [tutorial](https://www.karambelkar.info/2015/01/how-to-use-twitters-search-rest-api-most-effectively./).
This is my search query. 
`api.search(q="*", count=tweetsPerQry, lang ['ar'],tweet_mode='extended')`.  I expect to find a very large number of tweets, but I only collected about 7000 tweets.

- I checked the content of some of them and I noticed that they are posted in my country even I did not specify the location/Country (**Can anyone explain why this happen??).**

I tried to know the reason for finding a limited number of tweets, so I modified the query by replacing the *lang* parameter by *geocode* to find tweets in a city.  I fetched more than 65,000 Arabic tweets. After that, I used the *lang* parameter with the *geocode* and I found a very limited number of tweets.

- Can anyone help me to know **why I'm not able to get a large number of tweets when I used *lang* parameter?**

Comment: Public API is not a full archive endpoint. Twitter gives you whatever they want because there is to much tweets. Just a language search is too much. You should accurate with keywords, or try premium API.

Comment: I replaced  `lang['ar']` with `lang='ar'`. I don't know what is the difference, but It helps. I collected more than 100,000 tweets.

Answer (score 5):

The free twitter API's are good for small projects, but keep in mind that they don't display all of the tweets. Twitter has paid API's that are much more powerful, though what you are trying to achieve should be possible. I ran the query attached bellow, it seemed to work I was able to find a considerable amount of tweets. This method also seemed to work for @ebt_dev too I think it was just the structure of your request was set out like the stream listener version not the cursor search.

```
# Search Query change the X of .items(X) to the amount of tweets you are looking for
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q='*',tweet_mode='extended', lang='de').items(9999999):
    # Defining Tweets Creators Name
    tweettext = str( tweet.full_text.lower().encode('ascii',errors='ignore')) #encoding to get rid of characters that may not be able to be displayed
    # Defining Tweets Id
    tweetid = tweet.id

    # printing the text of the tweet
    print('\ntweet text: '+str(tweettext))
    # printing the id of the tweet
    print('tweet id: '+str(tweetid))
```